# How to apply coupon code programmatically in magento 1.9 in my custom module

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a coupon like 'DISC50'
I want to create this coupon in magento and apply this while magento cart page,how to do this?

can anyone give me sample of the exact observer event and function for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to you for applying coupon code programmatically with observer.

Here are the observer event names which you can use to trigger/handle event depending on your usage (**To apply coupon code**):

- sales_quote_save_before (most recommended)
- sales_quote_remove_item
- sales_quote_add_item
- sales_quote_product_add_after
- sales_quote_item_collection_products_after_load
- checkout_cart_add_product_complete
- checkout_cart_save_before
- checkout_cart_save_after

This is code snippet to apply coupon code.

```
function appplyDiscoCoupon($observer) {
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode)->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
    $quote->save();
}
```